# Elasticsearch - Any way to find out all the documents with field value as text

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

In the elasticsearch cluster, I accidentally pushed some text in a field which should ideally be a Number. Later, I fixed that and pushed the Number type value. Now, I wanted to fix it such that all the old values can be replaced by some Number for which I need to find out all the documents which are having this field as text.

Is there any elasticsearch query that I can use to get this information?

Comment: It would help if you could give us some concrete examples of what you did...

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be possible by using a nested `aggregations`.

At the top-level; use [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation to know text values, at the sub-level; use [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation to get `documents` that includes these values.

for instance:

```
GET example_index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "example_field.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "documents": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query; will return distinct values of the field, and the related `documents` in the sub-level, something like:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "NAME": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "mistake",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "documents": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 2,
              "max_score": 1,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "example_index",
                  "_type": "example_index",
                  "_id": "2QoDoXEBOCkJkkpwq5P0",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "example_field": "mistake"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "example_index",
                  "_type": "example_index",
                  "_id": "qAoDoXEBOCkJkkpwq5T0",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "example_field": "mistake"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "520",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "documents": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 1,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "example_index",
                  "_type": "example_index",
                  "_id": "5goDoXEBOCkJkkpwq5P0",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "example_field": "1"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I the example above; we need to delete the `documents` with `mistake` value, you can simply delete them by id.

NOTE: if you have a big index, it's rather to write a function inside your code that builds aggregations, gets the response, filters values if it can be parsed to a number, then removes documents by id.